# Vulkan: Is there a way to draw multiple objects in different locations like in DirectX12?

Tags: vulkan, directx-12

In DirectX12, you render multiple objects in different locations using the equivalent of a single uniform buffer for the world transform like:

```
// Basic simplified pseudocode
SetRootSignature();
SetPrimitiveTopology();
SetPipelineState();
SetDepthStencilTarget();
SetViewportAndScissor();

for (auto object : objects)
{
    SetIndexBuffer();
    SetVertexBuffer();

    struct VSConstants
    {
        QEDx12::Math::Matrix4 modelToProjection;
    } vsConstants;
    vsConstants.modelToProjection = ViewProjMat * object->GetWorldProj();
    SetDynamicConstantBufferView(0, sizeof(vsConstants), &vsConstants);

    DrawIndexed();
}
```

However, in Vulkan, if you do something similar with a single uniform buffer, all the objects are rendered in the location of last world matrix:

```
for (auto object : objects)
{
    SetIndexBuffer();
    SetVertexBuffer();

    UploadUniformBuffer(object->GetWorldProj());

    DrawIndexed();
}
```

Is there a way to draw multiple objects with a single uniform buffer in Vulkan, just like in DirectX12?

I'm aware of Sascha Willem's Dynamic uniform buffer example (https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/tree/master/dynamicuniformbuffer) where he packs many matrices in one big uniform buffer, and while useful, is not exactly what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot find a function called `SetDynamicConstantBufferView` in the D3D 12 API. I presume this is some function of your invention, but without knowing what it does, I can only really guess.

It looks like you're uploading data to the buffer object *while rendering*. If that's the case, well, Vulkan can't do that. And that's a *good thing*. Uploading to memory that you're currently reading from requires synchronization. You have to issue a barrier between the last rendering command that was reading the data you're about to overwrite, and the next rendering command. It's just not a good idea if you like performance.

But again, I'm not sure exactly what that function is doing, so my understanding may be wrong.

---

In Vulkan, descriptors are generally not meant to be changed in the middle of rendering a frame. However, the makers of Vulkan realized that users sometimes want to draw using different subsets of the same `VkBuffer` object. This is what dynamic uniform/storage buffers are for.

You technically don't have multiple uniform buffers; you just have one. But you can use the offset(s) provided to `vkCmdBindDescriptorSets` to shift where in that buffer the next rendering command(s) will get their data from. So it's a light-weight way to supply different rendering commands with different data.

Basically, you rebind your descriptor sets, but with different `pDynamicOffset` array values. To make these work, you need to plan ahead. Your pipeline layout has to explicitly declare those descriptors as being dynamic descriptors. And every time you bind the set, you'll need to provide the offset into the buffer used by that descriptor.

That being said, it would probably be better to make your uniform buffer store larger arrays of matrices, using the dynamic offset to jump from one block of matrices to the other. You would tehn

The point of that is that the uniform data you provide (depending on hardware) will remain in shader memory unless you do something to change the offset or shader. There is some small cost to uploading such data, so minimizing the need for such uploads is probably not a bad idea.

So you should go and upload *all* of your objects buffer data in a single DMA operation. Then you issue a barrier, and do your rendering, using dynamic offsets and such to tell each offset where it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to use Push constants or have separate uniform buffers for each location. These can be bound either with a descriptor per location of dynamic offset.

In Sasha's example you can have more than just the one matrix inside the uniform.

That means that inside UploadUniformBuffer you append the new matrix to the buffer and bind the new location.